# #include <QtWidgets>: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt5

Please don't crucify me. ChatGPT or Google did nothing, so here I am.
Basically, I cannot use QtWidgets in my C++ code (for some reason).

**The problem:**
When I include the `<QtWidgets>` header in C++, I get this error:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -Isrc/lib   -c src/ui/mainwindow.cpp -o bin/ui/mainwindow.o
src/ui/mainwindow.cpp:3:10: fatal error: QtWidgets: No such file or directory
    3 | #include <QtWidgets> //! doesn't work yet
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:34: bin/ui/mainwindow.o] Error 1
```

I tried re-installing the `qtbase5-dev` package from the Debian repositories.
I tried Googling and asking ChatGPT. I modified the Makefile like so:

```
# Makefile for Comet code editor

# Compiler
CC := g++
# Compiler flags
CFLAGS := -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra
CXXFLAGS += -I/usr/include/qt5
# Include directories
INCLUDE := -Isrc -Isrc/lib  # Adjust include paths based on your project structure

# Directories
SRCDIR := src
BUILDDIR := bin
BINDIR := bin

# Source files
SOURCES = src/main.cpp src/ui/mainwindow.cpp src/ui/mainwindow.hpp src/ui/mainwindow.css
# Object files
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp,$(BUILDDIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES))
# Target executable
TARGET := $(BINDIR)/comet

# Default target
all: $(TARGET)

# Linking
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET)

# Compiling source files
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c $< -o $@

# Run the comet executable
run: $(TARGET)
    ./$(TARGET)

# Cleaning
clean:
    rm -r $(BUILDDIR)

# Phony targets
.PHONY: all run clean
```

The code should render a basic window so far. But it doesn't.

Comment: The Qt path doesn't show up in the compilation command ..

Comment: Did you mean `#include <QWidget>`?

Comment: @Jarod42 no, it still produces an error.

Comment: @ChrisMM I'll give ya the command: CFLAGS := -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/include/qt5

Answer (score 0):

You have used both `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` in your Makefile. Why? One is enough. Naturally you should go with `CXXFLAGS` since you're working with a C++ compiler (in your case g++).

And the problem is that you have not used `CXXFLAGS` in your recipe for ***Compiling source files***. That variable contains the path to the include directory of Qt headers.